# Trying to access imageViews that reside in a TableLayout - Android

Tags: android

I have a TableLayout which has 3 TableRows and within the rows there are 3 ImageViews. What I am trying to do is iterate through the table and setImageResource for each ImageView in the table.
I have tried using this code, but I am getting stuck with this problem. I am a beginner at Android, any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

My code as follows...

```
TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
TableRow tableRow = (TableRow)tableLayout.getChildAt(0);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)tableRow.getChildAt(0);


int x = tableLayout.getChildCount();
for(int i = 0;  i < x; i++){
    tableRow= (TableRow)tableLayout.getChildAt(i);
    for( int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        imageView = (ImageView)tableRow.getChildAt(j);
        imageView.setImageResource(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you attach the error message ?

Comment: Maysara.. There is not an error, it just does not achieve the goal, it just setImageResource(0) to the first row only. I need to set all images on all 3 rows.

Comment: Try using the Hierarchy View in DDSM so you can see exactly what the xml looks like. It may make iterating the code easier.

Comment: Cory, thank you for your suggestion. But to be honest with you, I am not sure I would understand what I was reading, secondly I have not even used the Hierarchy View before, I am a beginner at Android. I will look at though in the future and figure out how to use it. Thank you again.

Comment: Can you verify that x really equals 3?

Comment: lionscribe, there are 3 rows within the TableLayout, so I would have to assume that x = 3.

Comment: Assumption don't seem to be helping here! You got to verify, and step through the code.

Comment: Ok sorry, but maybe I am not completely understanding here, I wrote the XML for the layout and I wrote a tablelayout with 3 rows and 3 imageviews in each row, i am not understanding why the code i wrote to iterate through the tables imageviews does not work. I am just a beginner here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Solved problem now, thanks for all help. Solved this way..'code'TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
          TableRow  tableRow = (TableRow)tableLayout.getChildAt(i);
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView)tableRow.getChildAt(j);
                imageView.setImageResource(0);
            }
        }'code'